# How to update the body and a hyperlink in a Word doc

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I managed to update the body of a Word document with the output of an XSL transformation. Now I have to add a hyperlink to the doc. The URL of a hyperlink goes to the `word/document.xml.rels` file in the zip-archive of the *.docx file, so I have to do more than just changing the XSL stylesheet.

The method of [this MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/83ea2c45-2091-4bf6-bab5-948d8fee0085/replace-hyperlinks-in-an-openxml-word-document) seems to work, but I cannot get it to work in combination of updating the body.

This is the code I am working on. It is a web application, so I am reading a template Word doc but not storing any files. The template Word doc is transfered to a `Stream`, modified as `Stream`, and eventually output as a `byte[]` array to be sent to the browser.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

public static void ReplaceDocumentXml(Stream fsDocx, string strDocumentXml, string LinkId, string LinkUrl)
{
    // Step 1: change the document body
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fsDocx, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
        // Replace the existing Document Body with the new content.
        mainPart.Document.Body = new Body(strDocumentXml);
        //Save the updated output document.
        //mainPart.Document.Save();
        doc.Save();
    }
    // Step 2: change the Hyperlink
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fsDocx, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;                
        // Search and delete the dummy hyperlink
        IEnumerable<Hyperlink> hLinks = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Hyperlink>();
        foreach (Hyperlink hLink in hLinks)
        {
            if (hLink != null && hLink.Id == LinkId)
            {
                // get hyperlink's relation Id (where path stores)
                HyperlinkRelationship hr = mainPart.HyperlinkRelationships.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == hLink.Id);
                if (hr == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    mainPart.DeleteReferenceRelationship(hr);
                    //mainPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri(LinkUrl, UriKind.Absolute), true, LinkId);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // add the actual hyperlink
        mainPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri(LinkUrl, UriKind.Absolute), true/*IsExternal*/, LinkId);
        //Save the updated output document.               
        doc.Save();
    }
    return;
}
```

The code is in two steps. I started with both steps in one `using` block, but because the hyperlink URL would not be found and replaced, I am trying to change the order. In this code I even save each modification separately.

The body is always updated OK, but the hyperlink gives troubles. If I change the hyperlink in step 1, step 2 seems to erase it from `document.xml.rels` . In the code as shown, the `foreach` loop does not find the id ("rId7") of the hyperlink, but also cannot add it, with exception

```
rId7 ID conflicts with the ID of an existing relationship for the specified source.
```

Now what am I doing wrong here? How to fix this problem?

For a similar project for Excel I found the `ClosedXML` package on github which tremendously simplifies using OpenXML and creating spreadsheets. Does something similar exist for creating Word docs?

**Edit**

The problem seems to be in the `Descendants<>` call; it returns no objects. Strange, because there certainly is one `Hyperlink` ( `<w:hyperlink r:id='rId7'>` ) tag.

I tried to find and count the many `<w:p>` elements:

```
IEnumerable<Paragraph> hParagraphs = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>();
int Dummy1 = hParagraphs.Count();
int I1 = 0;
foreach(Paragraph par in hParagraphs)
{
    I1++;
}
```

but find zero ( 0 ) elements.

Similar with table `<tbl>` elements, because most (all) text is in tables; getting zero items.

This is part of the actual document:

```
<w:tbl>
...
  <w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
      ...
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
         ...
      </w:pPr>
      <w:hyperlink r:id='rId7'>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            ...
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>click for settings</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:hyperlink>
    </w:p>
  </w:tc>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm on a mobile device so I can't do any in-depth research, but... Normally when using the SDK one doesn't pass a string like `rId7` - that could conflict with another relationship. Try with the overload that doesn't take an id for the relationship - then it will be generated by the software. OR pass a clearly custom ID that can't otherwise be present.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks. Will try this tomorrow, got to leave right now.

Comment: @CindyMeister I fixed a typo in the stylesheet, a wrong prefix, w:id corrected to r:id . Now I am zeroing in on why `Descendants()` does not find the hyperlink, see the updated question. Any ideas?